# Bind non-monadic functions to a monad

Tags: haskell, monads, function-composition

Maybe this is an often asked question, but I did not found an answer.

The bind of a monad is defined like that:

```
(>>=)  :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

At the moment I'm doing this:

```
foo :: Int
foo = sum $ ((*11) . (+2)) `map` [1..4]
```

I want to achieve a syntax like this, because I think it's more readable:

```
[1..4] >>= (+2) >>= (*11) >>= sum
```

I don't know the right operators instead of `>>=`.

Besides: foo is 198.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most readable in this case is certainly

```
   sum [ (x+2)*11 | x<-[1..4] ]
```

but if you want it point-free and without extra parens, just rewrite your original line with the [infix fmap operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36--62-):

```
   sum $ (*11) . (+2) <$> [1..4]
```

If you just want to turn the order around, you can replace `.` with the equivalent flipped operator [from `Control.Category`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Category.html#v:-62--62--62-), and `$` with [its flipped version e.g. from `lens`](http://ekmett.github.io/lens/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:-38-)

```
   [1..4] & fmap((+2)>>>(*11)) & sum
```

Then again, if you're after mathematical elegance and want it to "work like a monad", this isn't possible because there's nothing monadic going on here. You could however argue that `sum` is a Cokleisli arrow in the (not definable, in Haskell 98) `Monoid`-limited list comonad. We can approximate this by the [NonEmpty comonad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.15.2/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) and write

```
    extract $ fromList [1..4] =>> (extract>>>(+2)>>>(*11)) =>> sum.toList
```

but this is ridiculous.

Comment: When in doubt simply use *Cokleisli arrow in the Monoid-limited list comonad*. :-)

Comment: What is a monoid-limited list?

Comment: @J.Abrahamson: not monoid-limited list, monoid-limited comonad (i.e. `class MonComonad w where monExtract :: Monoid a => w a -> a`), of which `[]` is an instance.

Comment: Ah! I see. I'd just not heard that term before.